# Processwire can only visit root page and admin

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, processwire

I'm facing some issue with a processwire 3.0.123 installation. 
The admin works fine and I can edit and change stuff and view the root page of my Project. Whenver I try to visit any other site than `/` or `/admin` though, apache throws a 404.

I guess this has to do something with my htaccess, but I'm using the standard one which comes bundled with processwire and I've never had any issues with this when running it on a vagrant machine.
Right now I'm running it on my local machine on a local lamp stack with `mod_rewrite` enabled. The htaccess bundled with processwire features an option to rewrite certain urls in case of problems, I also tried these, to no avail though.

Below I have attached my htaccess, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Greetz derelektrischemoench

```
    #################################################################################################
# START PROCESSWIRE HTACCESS DIRECTIVES
# @version 3.0
# @indexVersion 300
#################################################################################################

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 1. Don't show directory indexes, but do follow symbolic links 
# 500 NOTE: Some cloud hosting companies don't allow +FollowSymLinks. 
# Uncomment +SymLinksifOwnerMatch and comment +FollowSymLinks if you have 500 errors. 
# If that doesn't resolve the error, then set it back to +FollowSymLinks. 
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
# Options +SymLinksifOwnerMatch

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 2. Let ProcessWire handle 404s
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 3. Handle request for missing favicon.ico/robots.txt files (no ending quote for Apache 1.3)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<Files favicon.ico>
  ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file favicon.ico was not found.
</Files>

<Files robots.txt>
  ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file robots.txt was not found.
</Files>

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 4. Protect from XSS with Apache headers
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # prevent site from being loaded in an iframe on another site
  # you will need to remove this one if you want to allow external iframes
  Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN 

  # to prevent cross site scripting (IE8+ proprietary)
  Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

  # prevent mime-based attacks via content sniffing (IE+Chrome)
  # Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" 
</IfModule>

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 5. Protect ProcessWire system files 
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<FilesMatch "\.(inc|info|info\.json|module|sh|sql)$|^\..*$|composer\.(json|lock)$">
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 6. Override a few PHP settings that can't be changed at runtime (not required)
# 500 NOTE: Try commenting out this entire section below if getting Apache 500 errors.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc     off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase      off
  php_flag register_globals     off
</IfModule>

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 7. Set default directory index files
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 8. ProcessWire requires mod_rewrite
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 9. If you only want to allow HTTPS, uncomment the RewriteCond and RewriteRule lines below.
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # If using an AWS load balancer, use these two lines below instead of those above:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http 
  # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 10. Set an environment variable so the installer can detect that mod_rewrite is active.
  # Note that some web hosts don't support this. If you get a 500 error, you might try 
  # commenting out this SetEnv line below. 
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  <IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
  </IfModule>

  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 11. OPTIONAL: Set a rewrite base if rewrites aren't working properly on your server.
  # And if your site directory starts with a "~" you will most likely have to use this.
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  # RewriteBase /
  # RewriteBase /pw/
  # RewriteBase /~user/

  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 12. Access Restrictions: Keep web users out of dirs that begin with a period,
  # but let services like Lets Encrypt use the webroot authentication method.
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  RewriteRule "(^|/)\.(?!well-known)" - [F]

  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 13. OPTIONAL: Redirect users to the 'www.' version of the site (uncomment to enable).
  # For example: http://processwire.com/ would be redirected to http://www.processwire.com/
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  # 14. OPTIONAL: Send URLs with non-ASCII name-format characters to 404 page (optimization)
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "[^-_.a-zA-Z0-9/~]"
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?it=/http404/ [L,QSA]

  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 15. Access Restrictions: Protect ProcessWire system files
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  # Allow screenshot files (for install.php only: this 1 line below may be removed after install)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^|/)site-[^/]+/install/[^/]+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$
  # Block access to any htaccess files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)\.htaccess$ [NC,OR]
  # Block access to protected assets directories
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/assets/(cache|logs|backups|sessions|config|install|tmp)($|/.*$) [OR]
  # Block acceess to the /site/install/ directory
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/install($|/.*$) [OR]
  # Block dirs in /site/assets/ dirs that start with a hyphen
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/assets.*/-.+/.* [OR]
  # Block access to /wire/config.php, /site/config.php, /site/config-dev.php, and /wire/index.config.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(wire|site|site-[^/]+)/(config|index\.config|config-dev)\.php$ [OR]
  # Block access to any PHP-based files in /templates-admin/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(wire|site|site-[^/]+)/templates-admin($|/|/.*\.(php|html?|tpl|inc))$ [OR]
  # Block access to any PHP or markup files in /site/templates/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/templates($|/|/.*\.(php|html?|tpl|inc))$ [OR]
  # Block access to any PHP files in /site/assets/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/assets($|/|/.*\.php)$ [OR]
  # Block access to any PHP files in core or core module directories
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)wire/(core|modules)/.*\.(php|inc|tpl|module|info\.json)$ [OR]
  # Block access to any PHP files in /site/modules/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/modules/.*\.(php|inc|tpl|module|info\.json)$ [OR]
  # Block access to any software identifying txt files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(COPYRIGHT|INSTALL|README|htaccess)\.(txt|md|textile)$ [OR]
  # Block all http access to the default/uninstalled site-default directory
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)site-default/
  # If any conditions above match, issue a 403 forbidden
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]

  # PW-PAGENAME
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  # 16a. Ensure that the URL follows the name-format specification required by PW
  # See also directive 16b below, you should choose and use either 16a or 16b. 
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/~?[-_.a-zA-Z0-9/]*$"

  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  # 16b. Alternative name-format specification for UTF8 page name support.
  # If used, comment out section 16a above and uncomment the directive below. If you have updated 
  # your $config->pageNameWhitelist make the characters below consistent with that. 
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/~?[-_./a-zA-Z0-9æåäßöüđжхцчшщюяàáâèéëêěìíïîõòóôøùúûůñçčćďĺľńňŕřšťýžабвгдеёзийклмнопрстуфыэęąśłżź]*$"

  # END-PW-PAGENAME
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 17. If the request is for a file or directory that physically exists on the server,
  # then don't give control to ProcessWire, and instead load the file
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)

  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 18. OPTIONAL: Prevent ProcessWire from attempting to serve images or anything in /site/assets/. 
  # Both of these lines are optional, but can help to reduce server load. However, they
  # are not compatible with the $config->pagefileSecure option (if enabled) and they 
  # may produce an Apache 404 rather than your regular 404. You may uncomment the two lines
  # below if you don't need to use the $config->pagefileSecure option. After uncommenting, test
  # a URL like domain.com/site/assets/files/test.jpg to make sure you are getting a 404 and not
  # your homepage. If getting your homepage, then either: do not use this option, or comment out 
  # section #2 above that makes ProcessWire the 404 handler. 
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(^|/)site/assets/

  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  # 19. Pass control to ProcessWire if all the above directives allow us to this point.
  # For regular VirtualHosts (most installs)
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?it=$1 [L,QSA]

  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  # 20. If using VirtualDocumentRoot (500 NOTE): comment out the one above and use this one instead
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?it=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment this line :

`# RewriteBase /`

Comment: I've already tried uncommenting this line, it didn't do any good, unfortunately.

Comment: It's a fresh installtion ? Which profile did you installed ?

Comment: It's a fresh installation, I installed the blank profile.

Comment: Juste to be sure, you added a template and a page and you are trying to visit it ?   Saying that just in case as the blank profile do not contain any page and thus lead to a 404 page.

Comment: I suggest you to move to the processwire forum and ask for help there.

Comment: Yes I added a template and selected it for the pages in question. This should work. Also in case anything template-related were to be misconfigured, processwire should in theory throw an exception, right? Debug mode is active, FYI.

Comment: True. Lets move to the chat if you want.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm on the road atm. But I might just get back to that offer as soon as I'm home.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203543/discussion-between-derelektrischemoench-and-jedot).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support so far. I found the culprit; it was myself. Turns out I should've created a template file to go with the template I selected in the backend. Once I did that, everything worked. Thanks for the support, nonetheless.